# Hive query to find a month for each year in which maximum number of quantities were sold

Tags: sql, database, hive, bigdata, hql

I have a data like below, from which i am trying to find out which month for each year has max quantity ordered

if the data is not showing clearly i have added a snip of it

QUANTITYORDERED QTR_ID  MONTH_ID    YEAR_ID
30  1   2   2003
34  2   5   2003
41  3   7   2003
45  3   8   2003
49  4   10  2003
36  4   10  2003
29  4   11  2003
48  4   11  2003
22  4   12  2003
41  1   1   2004
37  1   2   2004
23  2   4   2004
28  2   5   2004
34  2   6   2004
45  3   7   2004
36  3   8   2004
23  3   9   2004
41  4   10  2004
46  4   11  2004
42  4   11  2004
41  4   11  2004
20  4   12  2004
21  1   2   2005
42  1   3   2005
24  2   4   2005
66  2   5   2005
26  1   1   2003
29  1   3   2003
38  2   5   2003
37  3   7   2003
45  3   9   2003
21  4   10  2003

[image]

can someone please help me with the query

I have tried to group by year and month but not able to filter out other records other than the month that had max quantityorered

Comment: Hi - 1) please don't use images, add all information as editable text (so it can be copied if someone wants to try a solution 2) Format data as tables so that it is readable 3) Show the result you are trying to achieve, based on the sample data you've provided 4) Show the SQL that you've managed to write on your own 5) Ask a specific question about where you are facing an issue

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MaxQuantityPerYearMonth AS (
SELECT 
    YEAR_ID,
    MONTH_ID,
    MAX(QUANTITYORDERED) AS MaxQuantity
FROM 
    your_table_name
GROUP BY 
    YEAR_ID, 
    MONTH_ID
)
SELECT 
    YEAR_ID,
    MONTH_ID,
    MaxQuantity
FROM 
    MaxQuantityPerYearMonth
WHERE 
    (YEAR_ID, MaxQuantity) IN (
    SELECT 
        YEAR_ID, 
        MAX(MaxQuantity) AS MaxQuantity
    FROM 
        MaxQuantityPerYearMonth
    GROUP BY 
        YEAR_ID
    );
```